# NowJS current session

Tags: node.js, nowjs-sockets, everyauth

I am creating node.js app using express, everyauth and now.js.

I have a server-side now.js function in which I want to be able access the 'User' object for the authenticated user calling this function. I dont have access to the a 'request' or 'session' object, I only have the user cookie and connect.sid

My question is, whats best way to get the session information I'm looking for? Do I store these details in the cookie when the original page request comes in? Or Is there a way to get the session object from the `connect.sid`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this I created a Memory Session store, which I passed in when creating the Express App. Which allows me to access the session store

When a server-side nowjs function is called I use the connect.sid to retrieve the users session from the session store. This session then has all the authenticated users details.

Comment: Little bit more detail? Struggling with the same issue, using a Redis store. How do I get the session from that? Thanks

Comment: I wonder what is the use of a memory store if we can directly assign variables to `now` object. For example at client-side `now.User.name='Mr. Bentle`. Shouldn't this info be available at server-side (when Mr. Bentle makes a request to server) in `this.now.User.name`?

Comment: @juzerali - The user might modify his client to set now.User.name = 'whatever he wants'. It is better to do this server-side using sessions to avoid user shenanigans.